# How to make one div covering another div in different rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Bootstrap** framework and **jQuery** library are been used.

I have multiple `div`s in two different `row`s. I am using jQuery to change the div height in first row when mouse hover. Use of **z-index** and **absolute position** break Bootstrap responsivness.

Using **z-index** and **absolute position** with `.col-xs-*` can provide a working solution. However, the result is not mobile friendly.

#### The Current Situation

Both `div` `.site-box-id-01` and `.site-row-id-01` 's height change at the same time.

[image]
[image]

#### The Desired Result

Instead of changing the entire `row`'s height, I would like the first `div` to cover the second one after height changed. How should I implement this in Bootstrap without break responsiveness.

---

```js
 $(function() {
   console.log(">>> jQuery is ready");
   $(".site-box-id-01").mouseenter(function() {
     console.log(">>> mouse enter");
     $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
       height: "500px"
     }, {
       duration: 100
     });
   }).mouseleave(function() {
     console.log(">>> mouse leave");
     $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
       height: "300px"
     }, {
       duration: 100
     });
   });
 });
```

```css
.site-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.row {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 301px;
  /*      fix row height*/
}

.site-row-id-01 {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.site-row-id-02 {
  background-color: azure;
}

.site-box-id-01 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Moving Box</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="site-row-id-01">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 01</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 02</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 03</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-class-02" id="site-row-id-02">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-02">Test Box 04</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-02">Test Box 05</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-02">Test Box 06</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes to your **CSS**:

```
.site-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
.row {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 301px;
}
#site-row-id-01 {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
#site-row-id-02 {
  background-color: azure;
}

#site-box-id-01 {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Absolute positioned elements won't push the rest of the content down. Also a `z-index` property makes it sit on top of your second row.

See **[Example A](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwJyGz)**.

---

Otherwise, in a situation where you'll need to have multiple divs use jQuery  `.hover()` to target elements:

```
$(function() {
  $(".site-box").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', '1000');
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      height: "500px"
    }, {
      duration: 100
    });

  }, function(){
    $(this).css('z-index', '0');
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      height: "300px"
    }, {
      duration: 100
    });
  });
});
```

There are also few changes in the CSS, see **[Example B](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaroBJ)**.

---

If you change `width: 300px;` from `.site-box` to `width: 100%` and use `.col-sm-4 .col-xs-12` it will look as you requested for mobiles (resize the browser to see the effect).

See **[Example C](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myvXOW)**.

Comment: I was tring to avoid using `position:absolute` thinking that probably will break bootstpra responsiveness later. Indeed this is a working solution.

Comment: why should we add `.row-class-02` there? It's working without that class.

Comment: Oh, that's because of the `height` set on `.row ` class. Removed it.

Comment: so should we avoid set `height` on `.row` class? Because probably there are other `div`s with taller height.

Comment: Just use another class `<div class="row addheight">` then apply it on the `.addheight` this way `.row` will stay clean.

Comment: I have tried your solution in other situations, it does break the responsiveness. : (

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73730/discussion-between-cchacholiades-and-x-li).